# inner join 4 tables with group, order by, having clause

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have 4 table and i want to extract: `id`, `nume`, `localitate`, `masina_id`, `nr_inmatriculare`, `an_fabricatie`, `rafinarie`, `marca`, and sum `(quantity+deliver_quantity)` as `total_quantity` group by `an_fabricatie` , Order by `marca`, and put some `having clouse`.

I don’t know how to make this.

My query is as bellow , but I think isn't  correct.

```
    select c.id, c.nume,c.localitate,l.masina_id, i.nr_inmatriculare, i.an_fabricatie, 
i.rafinarie, m.marca from clienti c inner join livrari l on c.id = l.id  inner join incarcari I on l.incarcare_id = l.livrari_id inner join masina m on i.id_marca = m.id, sum(select quantity, deliver_quantity) as total_quantity  group by an_fabricatie having quantity >1000 order by marca;

Incarcari table
Id|livrari_id|id_marca|nr_inmatriculare|an_fabricatie|rafinarie|aviz_incarcare|quantity|

Livrari table
Id|masina_id|client_id|incarcare_id|deliver_quantity|aviz_livrare

Masini table
Id|numar_inmatriculare|marca|an_fabricatie|

Clienti table
Id|nume|localitate|date_add|date_upd|
```

Comment: Does your query produce an error?

Comment: Yes. error code 1064 you have an error  in your sql syntax

Comment: excellent, upvote and accept so people can see in the future

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT c.id, c.nume, c.localitate, l.masina_id, i.nr_inmatriculare, i.an_fabricatie, i.rafinarie, m.marca, (SUM(i.quantity) + SUM(l.deliver_quantity)) AS total_quantity
FROM clienti c 
INNER JOIN livrari l ON c.id = l.id 
INNER JOIN incarcari i ON l.incarcare_id = i.livrari_id 
INNER JOIN masini m ON i.id_marca = m.id
GROUP BY i.an_fabricatie, c.id, c.nume,c.localitate,l.masina_id, i.nr_inmatriculare, i.rafinarie, m.marca
HAVING i.quantity > 1000 
ORDER BY m.marca DESC;
```

Comment: when i run this scrip it's say: error code 1146 table biblioteca.masina doesn't exist.  biblioteca is my database. why involves my database?

Comment: @DanutMarianGabrian try now, there was a typo

Comment: For performance it's better to use `WHERE i.quantity > 1000` instead of having. The where clause must be before the GROUP BY